# Why does this configuration end up with an `index.htmlindex.html` url?

Tags: nginx

Likely extremely obvious for those who understand it, but I have been breaking my head over this for a couple of hours, using the following configuration:

```
root /var/www/web/public/;

location ~ ^[^.]+?$ {
    default_type text/html;
    alias /var/www/web/public/index.html;
}

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

I end up seeing (emphasis mine)

> 2016/01/26 18:56:59 [alert] 32364#32364: *1 "/var/www/web/public/**index.htmlindex.html**" is not a directory, client: 81.82.199.24, server: [...].com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", host: "[...]"

in my log when accessing the root of my server. My intended goal is to have requests without `.`'s in them go to `index.html` and the rest should just be staticly served.

So just to be extra clear about my intentions:

- `www.example.com/some/page` does not contain a `.` and thus is a page and should end in `index.html` (working)
- `www.example.com/some.file` contains a `.` and thus is a file and should serve the respective file (working)
- `www.example.com` does not contain a `.` and thus is a page and should end up in `index.html` (not working, tries to load index.htmlindex.html)

Comment: What on earth is that bizarre `location` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The first one should match any requests without a `.` in them (as in: urls which aren't to files). The second one is supposed to match everything else... O:) . Like honestly, this is the first time I am configuring nginx myself instead of colleagues doing it O:) .

Comment: Every location without a full stop is supposed to show the _same_ static page? That seems unlikely.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yep, `index.html` looks at the URL and dynamically loads the relevant parts of the application. The entire front end is a static affair with a dynamic API separately.

Comment: Then why the alias? You could just use `try_files`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Because I don't want to have all 404's go to `index.html`. I have seen a lot of applications do that and I think it's a terrible design choice (as it leads to html files being served when for example images miss). But it might be that `alias` isn't the right way to do this... after all, that `index.htmlindex.html` sure is unintended... but resource requests and page requests both work now, it's just requests to the root which don't :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34889/discussion-between-david-mulder-and-michael-hampton).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
alias /var/www/web/public/index.html;
```

with

```
alias /var/www/web/public/;
```

And make sure your main config has this (or similar) in it so Nginx knows to show index.html when the user requests a directory

```
index index.php index.htm index.html;
```